# Find the password for the currently connected wireless network

Tags: wireless, password

I want to find the password for the wireless network that I am currently connected to (and I entered the password when connecting to the network). How can I do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: I went to "connection information" and didn't find the password.

Comment: almost there... you need the `edit connections` below that ;)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Left click the `connections` icon at the top right.

Choose `edit connections` and then choose `edit` on the connection you need and click the `wireless security`.

[image: 1]

And click the 'show password'checkbox

[image: 2]

Comment: Ah, my command-line ways were betrayed by my solution :) I like this one better, FWIW.

Comment: Well I like both with a preference to command line @roadmr :D

Answer (score 46):

If you want to do this with the command line, the wireless network configuration files are saved in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory. You can get them all at once like this:

```sh
sudo grep -r '^psk=' /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

This will give you output like this:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyExampleSSID:psk=12345
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AnotherSSID:psk=password
```

You can suppress the filename with the `-h` flag:

```sh
sudo grep -hr '^psk=' /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

The output is easier to read at a glance:

```
psk=12345
psk=password
```

Comment: This is working charmly

Answer (score 21):

In the command line:

```
nmcli dev wifi show-password
```

Comment: First one down the line that worked perfectly.

Comment: This one is not only the only working solution for me, but it even displays a nice Qr code (yes in command line!) that you can scan on your mobile to quickly add the wifi! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17):

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then type:

```
sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<your-SSID>
```

(Of course, substitute *`<your-SSID>`* with your network's name.)

Look for the line named `psk`. This should contain your password, after the `=` sign.

```
psk=notreallymypassword
```

Answer (score 4):

This will give you the password for your current connection.

```
sudo grep psk= /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

Or

```
sudo grep psk= /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/(YOUR-SSID)
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a one liner to make @David Foerster answer more useful

```
MYCWD=`pwd`; cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ ; sudo grep -e '^psk=' * | less ; cd $MYCWD
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just type `ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`
and it will show the name of your network, so just press the up arrow on keyboard and type the name of your connections and change `ls` to `sudo cat`

the password will be `psk`

Answer (score 1):

Using nmcli on Ubuntu 18.04, replace WIFINAME with the wireless network name (ssid):

```
nmcli --show-secrets connection show WIFINAME | grep 802-11-wireless-security.psk:
```

show-password does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Going further with MRTgang second command to remove "psk=" leaving only the password

```
sudo grep -hr '^psk=' /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ | sed 's|psk=||g'
```