# How to hack Wifi Keys in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

I'm using 12.04. Now, I would like to crack wifi keys. Is it possible? Then please show me the process or software.

Comment: are u sure its legal??

Comment: no hacking required if you own the system: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156861/find-the-password-for-the-currently-connected-wireless-network

Comment: @Stormvirux now for the trick question... if the software to do this is in our own ubuntu software center is there then need to ask that question?

Comment: "Cracking a WiFi" doesn't sound like a legal request anywhere.

Comment: @guntbert: One might want to crack their own Wifi for academic purposes. I attended a workshop with that exact aim.

Comment: @DavidFoerster theoretically true, but I expect a different attitude from someone trying to learn.

Comment: @guntbert: Agreed.

Answer (score 5):

For finding WEP/WPA keys you can use `aircrack-ng`. It is in the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

[image]

There is also `kismet`

```
sudo apt-get install kismet
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Show me the process. Somewhere in the web I read that both tools are not work properly and create problems. So, what would be the easy solution?

Comment: "But Show me the process" well personally I would not want you near my wireless and I can imagine others feel the same >:-D I can tell you it does work but it is not an "works out of the box" tool. It requires a good setup and mosttimes that setup only applies to your case. I would continue this here: http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=338  :-)

Comment: I'm failed to install air crack.