# How to install ubuntu on a chromebook without developer mode? Or enter developer mode without wiping system information (wifi)?

Tags: boot, system-installation, chromebook

In advance i'd like to thank you for your help. First off, I have installed Ubuntu (Linux) on my chromebook but the problem is it wipes the data and I need the wifi to stay and not forget the network because I need it to remember my school wifi password. So I did it and then he turned developer mode back on without realising so now I can't access it. So, I don't want to go back to him for the wifi password ever again. Anyways, I want to know if there is a way to install it without developer mode of without wiping the wifi password and more. I have also thought of installing ubuntu on a bootable flash drive but again I don't think it's possible yet to boot the chromebook from the flash drive without entering developer mode. You'd think there would be a way to do it by now but I've searched so much and haven't found anything so PLEASE give me a way to do this!

Thanks,

-Josh

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to install Ubuntu on a Chromebook without entering Developer Mode because that would completely defeat its purpose and create a huge security hole.

Anyway, you could simply [look at the WiFi password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156861/find-the-password-for-the-currently-connected-wireless-network) and write it down I guess using the Network Manager.